# TypeScript 2.x and LINQ

Tags: linq, typescript

1. From what I have read about TS 2.2 there is no LINQ support? (I am only interested in support for JS collections, not database access)
2. Is LINQ support planned or should I go looking for a library on
   GitHub as there appear to be a number on there.

Comment: Are you trying to access the database through linq or just working with the collections in typescript? In the first case, do it on the backend, in the 2nd case you some library like _ (underscore) which works with typescript

Comment: LINQ as in the syntatic sugar of `from collection select fieldName` or LINQ as in the extension methods of `collection.Where(t => t.Field).Select(t => t.OtherField)`?  In both cases the answer is "yes, there is no LINQ support, now or planned".  Try [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Comment: For the most part, TypeScript only adds features that mirror the official ECMAScript standards. Someone would have to propose adding LINQ to JS, and the proposal would have to reach at least stage 2 and maybe stage 3 before TS would implement it.